# Mobile Media Converter stoped conversion

Tags: media, video-conversion

I love this super handy and versatile tool [Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverterUbuntu.php) but after the last upgrade to mmc_1.8.2_amd64.deb, it fails to convert any video formats. I tried to reinstall it several times but with no avail. Appreciate your hints to fix it.

p.s. Just noticed that Medibuntu came to an end and MMC [depends](http://www.medibuntu.org/repository.php) on it. So what to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: 
As for June 2014, on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, the latest deb file (mmc_1.8.4_i386_multiarch.deb) gave a i386 not found error and  did not install, but I could install mmc_1.8.2_amd64.deb from [this page](http://miksoft.net/products/mmc-older/), using [this](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg) ffmpeg repo.