# Unknown encoder 'libvo_aacenc'

Tags: ffmpeg, codecs, conversion

I get this error when I try to convert an wmv to 3gp using this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "inputvid.wmv" -vf scale=352:288 \
       -f 3gp -vcodec h263 -r 15 -b:v 200k \
       -acodec libvo_aacenc -ac 2 -ar 32000 -b:v 64k \
       "outputvid.3gp"
```

(The command is actually derived from  [Mobile Media Converter 1.8.2](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverterUbuntu.php) which recently [fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347650/mobile-media-converter-stoped-conversion) on each conversion and I'm trying to troubleshoot.)

I have made the latest stable `ffmpeg` (version `0.10.8-7:0.10.8-1~raring1`) using [these instruction](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide#Examples).

I appreciate your hints to either install `libvo_aacenc`, or some other codec to make conversion possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinFF (FFMPEG): Unknown encoder 'libvo\_aacenc'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483187/winff-ffmpeg-unknown-encoder-libvo-aacenc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to make the command work,  I just needed to revert the  install ([Reverting Changes Made by This Guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide)) and start again but add '--enable-libvo-aacenc' to 
ffmpeg .configure flags.

Comment: If you've gone to the trouble of compiling it yourself anyway, you might as well use libfdk_aac instead, as it will give you much better quality audio.

Comment: Agreed. In fact, libvo_aacenc is worse than the native FFmpeg AAC encoder (`-codec:a aac -strict experimental`) which is currently being worked on and is improving.

Comment: Now `aac` is no longer experimental, so `-strict` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

This solves it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra
```

Maybe this post has an answer, but for Googlers...

Answer (score 2):

libvo_aacenc was low quality and [FFmpeg removed support for this encoder](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=e07e88cd82f78644ddcb10d7d3e0dd624fffe274).

Use `-c:a aac` or `-c:a libfdk_aac` instead.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

It's Easy 
Only Follow the next instructions 
Open the terminal 
cd ~
wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
   --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --extra-libs="-ldl" --enable-gpl \
   --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus \
   --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-version3
(IN this part you have been enabled the libvo-aacenc & the version 3 of the same)

make
make install
make distclean
hash -r
Your converter is ready.

Comment: Looks like you copied and pasted this from the [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) and added `--enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-version3`.