# WinFF (FFMPEG): Unknown encoder 'libvo_aacenc'

Tags: convert, video-conversion, aac, winff

When I try to convert a video - specifically, a Video Object (".vob") file - to MPEG-4, WinFF which I assume is a frontend for `ffmpeg` and `avconv`, but it tells me:

```
`Unknown encoder 'libvo_aacenc'`
```

The full text from Terminal is:

```
avconv version 9.13-6:9.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
built on May  9 2014 13:34:03 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[mpeg @ 0x1924160] max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, mpeg, from '/media/gregoryopera/Movies/Get a Horse!.vob':
 Duration: 00:00:04.37, start: 0.221156, bitrate: 631225 kb/s
Stream #0.0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x576 [PAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 9800 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0.1[0x20]: Subtitle: dvdsub
Stream #0.2[0x21]: Subtitle: dvdsub
Stream #0.3[0x22]: Subtitle: dvdsub
Stream #0.4[0x23]: Subtitle: dvdsub
Stream #0.5[0x24]: Subtitle: dvdsub
Stream #0.6[0x25]: Subtitle: dvdsub
Stream #0.7[0x26]: Subtitle: dvdsub
Stream #0.8[0x27]: Subtitle: dvdsub
Stream #0.9[0x28]: Subtitle: dvdsub
Stream #0.10[0x29]: Subtitle: dvdsub
Stream #0.11[0x2a]: Subtitle: dvdsub
Stream #0.12[0x2b]: Subtitle: dvdsub
Stream #0.13[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 384 kb/s
Stream #0.14[0x81]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
Stream #0.15[0x82]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 384 kb/s
Stream #0.16[0x83]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 384 kb/s
Stream #0.17[0x84]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 384 kb/s
Unknown encoder 'libvo_aacenc'
Press Enter to Continue*
```

When I press "Enter", Terminal closes and my conversion is canceled.

And before anyone says it - I *did* find the other answer relating to this *same* question here on Ask Ubuntu... However that guy compiled it from scratch, which I do not want to do (for a start, I wouldn't know where to begin!)...

Comment: I have the same problem. But libvo-aacenc0 is already installed.

Answer (score 15):

I confirm with vinay, but you must modify a command line to this:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra
```

P.S. Edited command.

Answer (score 12):

libvo_aacenc was low quality and [FFmpeg removed support for this encoder](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=e07e88cd82f78644ddcb10d7d3e0dd624fffe274).

Use `-c:a aac` or `-c:a libfdk_aac` instead.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-54
```

Based on  [this instant of this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMGK8YtzZN4#t=35)

Answer (score 0):

Install the visualon AAC encoder library

```
sudo apt-get install libvo-aacenc0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had luck with:

`sudo apt-get install libvo-aacenc-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not much of an expert, but this worked for me:

when I entered the files I wanted to convert, I took a look at the options. In the "ffmpeg" tab there was this code... I just replaced the "libvo_aacenc" with "libfdk_aac", started the converting and it worked... maybe someone more into this can explain what exactly happened... :)