# Unknown encoder 'libvo_aacenc' Error

Tags: apt, video, directory, ffmpeg, libav

I have installed x262 library then installed ffmpeg into /var/www/html/GetVideo directory with these commands.

```
# build and install x264
git clone --depth 1 git://git.videolan.org/x264
cd x264
./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --enable-static --disable-opencl
make -j 4
sudo make install

# build and make ffmpeg
git clone --depth=1 git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git
cd ffmpeg
./configure --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
make -j4
sudo make install
```

So, i have a /var/www/html/GetVideo/x264 library and /var/www/html/GetVideo/x264/ffmpeg directories.

Then i have installed libav codecs by

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-54
```

Then i have tried to change the frame size and frame rate.

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/GetVideo/video/20180503145826-8849_1080.mp4 -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec libx264 -s 1920x1080 -r 60 -strict experimental /var/www/html/GetVideo/video/output.mp4
```

Although i have installed libav codec i am still getting Unknown encoder 'libvo_aacenc' error. I don't know where am i missing? How can i resize the videos?

Comment: FFmpeg removed support for this low quality encoder. Use `-c:a aac` (`-acodec aac`) instead. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034195/59378). Additionally, the libavcodec-extra-54 only affects the ffmpeg package from the repository: it does nothing to your compiled `ffmpeg`. Unrelated, but you did not need `--enable-nonfree` because you didn't enable any additional non-free components. You don't need `-strict experimental` either.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have installed libvo-aacenc0 but still same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## FFmpeg no longer supports libvo_aacenc

It is a low quality encoder and could only encode up to two channels. The built-in FFmpeg AAC encoder was improved to the point that libvo_aacenc was no longer needed, so support for [libvo_aacenc was removed from FFmpeg](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=e07e88cd82f78644ddcb10d7d3e0dd624fffe274).

Use a recent `ffmpeg` and use the built-in AAC encoder. So instead of `-acodec libvo_aacenc` use `-acodec aac` (or `-c:a aac`).

## You can't just install codecs and assume `ffmpeg` can use them

Installing `libavcodec-extra-54` will not do anything if you want to compile `ffmpeg`. When compiling, to add support for external codec libraries, you need to:

1. Install the relevant **-dev** packages. For example **libx264-dev** for H.264 video encoding.
2. Use the appropriate `./configure` option to enable it in `ffmpeg`, such as `--enable-libx264`. See `./configure --help` for a list of supported external codec libraries.
3. Compile `ffmpeg`.

If you want to compile see [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile for Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) for a step-by-step guide.

However, installing **libavcodec-extra-54** will add additional codecs to `ffmpeg` from the repository (which additional codecs I am not sure anymore).

## Why are you compiling?

`ffmpeg` is available in the Ubuntu repository. Why not just use that?

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

If there are missing features you can consider compiling.

## How can I resize the videos?

Now to address your actual goal. By "resize" I assume you want to scale the video. Here's a simple example using the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -vf scale=1920:1080 output.mp4
```

In this example the audio is being [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) because input and output are both MP4, and the audio is likely already AAC, so just copy it instead of re-encoding.

Comment: I have added setdar=16/9 in your code and its solved. Thank you for detailed explanation.